# How navigate to another page without using a button?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

i'm developing a Windows Phone app, and I need redirect the user to another page if a condition is false. Therefore without button use.

I'm trying use a "normal" code way:

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

 if (iso.Contains("isoServer") == false)
        {
            iso["isoServer"] = "http://domain.com/appTerminalBD";
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/tuto.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
    }
```

But return this error:

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Which line is it throwing the exception on? One of your variables is null

Comment: This line: `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/tuto.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));`

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line, my guess is NavigationService is null. When it breaks, hover over it to see its value

Comment: you are correct, NavigationService is null. But how solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`NavigationService` is a property of `PhoneApplicationPage` that is set after navigation.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (iso.Contains("isoServer") == false)
    {
        iso["isoServer"] = "http://domain.com/appTerminalBD";
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/tuto.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
}
```

Comment: But how is correct mode to invoke this method on the constructor?

Comment: @ReneSá Why would you want to do this in the constructor in the first place? That doesn't make much sense. When you immediately navigate in `OnNavigatedTo`, the MainPage won't appear.

Comment: I understand. But my doubt is how call this method on constructor

Comment: @ReneSá In the case of MainPage being your navigation page (first page of the app), you cannot (in any case, you shouldn't). Other way to navigate is: `((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Navigate(new Uri(...))`, but the RootVisual isn't initialized either during the construction, so you'll get NullReference using this method also.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! So, I need open this page on construction of the MainPage, because the "tuto.xaml" page is a tutorial for first use. How a best way for this? Or there is no way?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the code below and this code works fine for me:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

if (iso.Contains("isoServer") == false)
    {
        iso["isoServer"] = "http://domain.com/appTerminalBD";
        this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
             {
                 var ns = NavigationService;
                 ns.Navigate(new Uri("/tuto.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
             };
    }
}
```

Comment: The navigation code doesn't execute during the construction! It's only hooked to `Loaded` event during construction. It executes long after that, in fact, it executes even later than my code with OnNavigatedTo (OnNavigatedTo is executed first, Loaded later).